# Where do I put this automapping?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

HI

I have 2 projects one for my repos and service layers(data project) and one for my views,controllers(webUI project).

I am using automapper and I have been doing all my mapping in my controller. Say I had a request to get a item. It would go to my controller it would contact the service layer and any business logic would be done at this time.

I would get usually a domain model back and I would take that model and in the controller I would auto map it too a view model. Then send the View model back.

This has been working quite well as I been able to keep my mvc code(my viewModels and etc) out of my service layer.

However there have been 2 cases where I need to use automapper to do mapping in the service layer.

This mapping in the service layer is too other domain objects and has been quite small right now(only a few properties).

Should I be doing mapping in my service layer?

If so where do I stick these mappings? Right now I have it just in my project with my controllers that get registered in application start.

So one option could be to put my mapping where I been putting mapping(in a class in my models folder). The problem with this would be that if I take my service layer and pop it into another project(say a mobile device) then I have to redo all the mapping as it won't exist.

So any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have a class in your service layer called "ServiceLayerMappings" and call that from application start.

If you reuse the service layer just call ServiceLayerMappings.MapThisStuff() or whatever and you're all set.

```
public class ServiceLayerMappings
{
     public void Map()
     {

        Mapper.CreateMap<MyServiceClass, ServiceDto>();
     }
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         new ServiceLayerMappings().Map()
```

You could of course make this static or rename.  It doesn't matter.

Comment: would you please explain how to use this in application start and how this class is meant to be implemented and maintained

Comment: I finally around to sort of trying this but I am doing my stuff a bit differently. I am using Register(RegisterServiceLayerMaps.Register();) instead of what you doing. Can you only have one register method or something? Since it seems to cause my working automappers to crash when I register twice.